# what is the operator be overloading here :　String8::operator const char*() const

Tags: c++, android

I know it is used to get the containing c string ,similar to `std::string.c_str().` But how should I use the operator?

```
//android/frameworks/base/include/utils/String8.h
458 inline String8::operator const char*() const
459 {  
460     return mString;
461 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), which allows you to convert from a user-defined type to another type.

You could do stuff like this, by using it to get a `const char*` from a `String8` object.

```
String8 str = "Hello";
const char *cptr = str; // gets const char* from str

std::strlen(str); // std::strlen expects a const char*
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much about how you use it (explicitly), as letting it be used implicitly.  Where you'd use `.c_str()` for a `std::string`, just leave off the `.c_str()`.  Of course the problem is ambiguity: `std::string` lacks such an operator for a good reason, and you may occasionally find yourself having to explicitly invoke the operator so the compiler knows which behaviour to use.

EDIT: example in response to UncleBens' comment:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    operator const char*() { return "hello world\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    X x;

    std::cout << x.operator const char*();
}
```

Comment: Explicitly invoking the operator means casting a String8 to char pointer?

Comment: @UncleBens: please see example added to answer.